# bootstrap slider in libraries are changing the all other layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a slider from here:

https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/pLGzgo

And the code of the complete page:

paste.ofcode.org/Dx5NyPRunupjL6GRysUx9g

But after adding these libraries, the other layouts of the web page don't display fine and the display is wrong. How can i avoid this?

ejs code:

```
           <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

                           <!-- The slideshow -->
                           <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
                             <!-- mapping your meetings parent -->
                             <% meetings.forEach(function(meeting,index){ %>
                             <div class="carousel-item <%= index === 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
                               <!-- mapping your meetings child -->
                               <% meeting.forEach(function(m){ %>
                               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn">
                                   <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                     <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= m.subject %></p>
                                     <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"><%= convertDate(m.date) %></p>
                                     <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
                                   </span>
                                 </div> 
                               </div>    
                               <% }) %>   
                             </div>
                           <% }) %>   
                           </div>

                           <!-- Left and right controls -->
                           <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                             <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                           </a>
                           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                             <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                           </a>
                         </div>
```

and its libraries are

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your slider items are missing the `carousel-item` selector

Comment: @M0ns1f look at the bottom of 1st foreach its there  "carousel-item"

Comment: can you see it there is any error in your console ?

Comment: no  error in console

Comment: then you should close this question, there is no error only that you want to show multi images in slide item, that what explain the behavior of the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!important` with your all those items which has the same classes, otherwise change your slider that will fit into your page.